# What's wrong with this proof of Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means

Tags: inequality

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxT90.png)

I can't find the error in this proof. Everything looks so perfect

Comment: Well, as stated all the implications are one way.  That is, each statement implies its successor.  That's not a proof (since false things can imply true things).  To fix it, just argue that in fact each implication goes both ways, i.e. is "if and only if".

Comment: Aren't you assuming what you want to prove in the first step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that a statement $P$ implies a true statement does **not** tell you that $P$ itself is true. For instance, statement $-1=1$ implies that $(-1)^2=1^2$, which is true, but that certainly doesn’t mean that $-1$ really is equal to $1$. However, if the argument started with the true statement that $(a-b)^2\ge 0$ and proceeded **up** the chain of statements, it **would** constitute a proof of the inequality (though one would have to justify the step from $a^2+2ab+b^2\ge 4ab$ to $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$ by noting that $a$ and $b$ are non-negative).